# Cannot resolve stack() due to type mismatch

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark code that looks like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
unpivotExpr = """stack(14, 'UeEnd', UeEnd, 
    'Encedreco', Endereco,
    'UeSitFun', UeSitFun,
    'SitacaoEscola', SituacaoEscola, 
    'Creche', Creche, 
    'PreEscola', PreEscola, 
    'FundAnosIniciais', FundAnosIniciais, 
    'FundAnosFinais', FundAnosFinais, 
    'EnsinoMedio', EnsinoMedio, 
    'Profissionalizante', Profissionalizante, 
    'EJA', EJA, 
    'EdEspecial', EdEspecial, 
    'Conveniada', Conveniada,
    'TipoAtoCriacao', TipoAtoCriacao)
    as (atributo, valor)"""

unpivotDf = df.select("Id", expr(unpivotExpr))
```

When I run it I get this Error:

```
cannot resolve 'stack(14, 'UeEnd', `UeEnd`, 'Encedreco', `Endereco`, 'UeSitFun', `UeSitFun`,
'SitacaoEscola', `SituacaoEscola`, 'Creche', `Creche`, 'PreEscola', `PreEscola`,
'FundAnosIniciais', `FundAnosIniciais`, 'FundAnosFinais', `FundAnosFinais`, 'EnsinoMedio',
`EnsinoMedio`, 'Profissionalizante', `Profissionalizante`, 'EJA', `EJA`, 'EdEspecial',
`EdEspecial`, 'Conveniada', `Conveniada`, 'TipoAtoCriacao', `TipoAtoCriacao`)'
due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (string) != Argument 6 (bigint); line 1 pos 0;
```

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Please share the schema and a sample from the pivot df

Comment: @NetanelMalka Oh, now I see, all of the values of those columns are going to end up in a single column, so if they have different types it should not work. Thanks for making me realise what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you unpivot a group of columns, all of their values are going to end up in the same column. Because of that, you should first make sure that all of the columns you are trying to unpivot into one have the same data types. Otherwise you would have a column with multiple different types in different rows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).